# For Loop Only Outputting API Data for the Last Item in the List

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, google-search-console

I am trying to use two for loops to extract all the data from an API request where Loop 1) requests the data from the API day by day - while nested within that - Loop 2) goes through each page in a list of URLs I want to get data for.

The issue I'm encountering is that it will loop through all the days fine, just it will only return data for the last list in the URL array.

```
pages = read_page_paths_from_file(PAGE_FILTERS, PROPERTY_URI) # stores in a list
start_date = datetime.strptime(START_DATE, "%Y-%m-%d")
end_date = datetime.strptime(END_DATE, "%Y-%m-%d")

output_rows = []

for day in date_range(start_date, end_date, delta=timedelta(days=1)):
    day = day.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

    for i in range(len(pages)):
        request = {
                'startDate': day,
                'endDate': day,
                'dimensions': ['date','query','page'],
                'rowLimit': 1000,
                'dimensionFilterGroups' : [
                    {
                      "filters": [
                        {
                          "dimension": "page",
                          "expression": pages[i]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }

    response = execute_request(webmaster_service, PROPERTY_URI, request)
    time.sleep(1)

    if response is None:
        logging.error("Request failed %s", json.dumps(request, indent=2))
        continue

    for row in response['rows']:
        keys = ','.join(row['keys'])
        date, query, page = keys.split(",")
        output_row = [date, query, page, row['clicks'], row['impressions'], row['ctr'], row['position']]
        output_rows.append(output_row)
```

What I'd like is to get the data for each URL in the list as well as the data for that URL for each day in the date range.

However instead what I'm getting is the data for all 7 days, but only on the last URL in the list.